# MySQL show only matched data not everything

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have attribute of datatype longtext in which there is on average 3 MB of plain text.
Without using fulltext search or any kind I use this query:

```
select column1 from table where column1 like '%abc5%';
```

The output for each row is the whole content of column1. So if I would like to color matched data in PHP I would have to use:

```
<?php
 preg_replace('/(abc5)/i', "<b>$1</b>", $row->column1);
 ....
?>
```

This goes throught all content. Is there a way that I could do something like this:

```
select show_first_N_matched(column1) from table where column1 like '%abc5%';
```

Let's say I have for example data like this:

```
 abc1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 abc2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 abc3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 abc4   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 abc5   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 abc4   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 abc5   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

The first query would return everything. The second gives only this:

```
abc5    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
abc5    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: Assuming the example data is in one field: not possible in backend afaik.

Comment: Yes the example data is one field.